# ajax call executing twice

Tags: ajax, bootstrap-modal

Hello Everyone i have modal dialog that trigger database insertion when it has been closed. However when i check my table in DB i often duplicate insertion.
The insertion is done thru ajax call. Here is my source code

```
$(`#closingModal-${alertId}`).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e)
{
     //..Load la map pour la localisation du badge d'alerte
    loadMapByMacAddress(macAddress)


    //..Inserer dans la BD le nom de l'utilisateur qui a ferme le modal
    const alarmId = parseInt(alertId.replace('alerte', ''));
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Observer/SetStopDynamicAlarm",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            LastUpdate: dateFermeture.toJSON(),
            AlarmId: alarmId
        }
    });


    $(this).remove();



});
```

I don't really any error in the above source code. Any help woud be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Is it possible that the hidden.bs.modal event gets triggered multiple times?

Comment: same thing happen when i moved the above code in the hid.bs.modal event, i got double insertion.

Comment: There's only one AJAX call being made here.  Does this code get executed twice?  Does the server-side code produce duplicate records?  You're going to need to debug and narrow down the problem a bit.

Comment: I think the event gets triggered twice instead of once

Comment: how can i prevent the modal from being triggered twice ?

Comment: I did the investigation the modal is triggered twice . when i put the console log in the above code i got twice the console logs

Comment: @Xris: Where are you hiding the modal?  Any chance that you're telling it to hide twice?

Comment: i don't call hide programmitically, it happens when i close the x button of the modal which has data-dismiss attribute

Comment: i create a post at the following links describing the real problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56192081/a-function-get-called-twice-in-a-for-loop-javascript